# Iterate list to create multiple rows in pyspark based on count

Tags: list, loops

I need to group the rows based on state and create list for cities in which list should not exceed more than 5 elements per row. If there are 8 cities for a state, it shd be created as 2 rows where first row will have 5 cities in a list and second row wud have rest of the 3 cities in the list .

```
+-------+-----+---------+-----+
|country|state|     city|count|
+-------+-----+---------+-----+
|    USA|   CA|       LA|    1|
|    USA|   CA| SAN JOSE|    1|
|    USA|   CA|  OAKLAND|    1|
|    USA|   CA|SAN DEIGO|    1|
+-------+-----+---------+-----+
```

Example:
I need to split above example into multiplerows where each row containing 3 cities in list as example.  Here it wud be 2 rows in result .

Expected Result

```
+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|country|state|city                   |
+-------+-----+-----------------------+
|USA    |CA   |[LA, SAN JOSE, OAKLAND]|
|USA    |CA   |[SAN DEIGO]            |
+-------+-----+-----------------------+
```

I aggregated and created 1 row as below

```
+-------+-----+----------------------------------+---+
|country|state|city_list                         |sum|
+-------+-----+----------------------------------+---+
|USA    |CA   |[LA, SAN JOSE, OAKLAND, SAN DEIGO]|4  |
+-------+-----+----------------------------------+---+
```

where the list has all cities but I need to split it multiple rows based on limit in the list per row